# Kentico - Increase limit of rich text editor

Tags: kentico

We are using Kentico 10 and found out there is a limit of 3000 characters on RichTextBox. Can we increase it? On database we are using NVARCHAR(MAX).

The column is expected to hold around 10000 characters.

Thanks

Comment: No need to cross post on SO and Kentico DevNet as the DevNet reads from both.

https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/increase-limit-of-rich-text-editor

Comment: Sorry wrong question, there was Maximum text length property whose length was set to 3000 characters.